# Stop Image load on append 2nd time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, caching

I am developing an chat application and it appends data like below

```
   $(selector).append("<img src='image.php?id=username'><div id ='msg'>hi</div>");
```

So each time when same image is appended , Its requesting the  image URL again and again .

How to stop the image refresh on append , If the image url is already loaded, I want it to load that image cache.

Comment: If you add an img tag to the page and that exact same image src is already part of the page, I would expect the new image tag to be a cache hit and not download the image again.  Have you used browser dev tools to determine that the image is being downloaded each time (or not)?

Comment: yupe each time http request is sent to load same image url....Its a chat application.you cant expect an app to preload all users image in html body...

Comment: are you sure that http request is sent? maybe its from cache, doesn't it?

Comment: I am very sure.. request is sent http://prntscr.com/6kcyb0, I use live http headers and also chrome dev tool...is it because image is loaded via php ? ex : domain.com/thumb.php?id=img

Comment: That could be related. Compare the headers of a request for a basic image loaded from your server's filesystem, to the thumb.php request. If you're finding your image in a database dynamically, you may need to code the proper cache-response headers in your PHP file manually.

Comment: Yes, it is because of php, unless you took care of cache control in php script. You can't resolve caching issues in js.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could clone the already existing Element. That way all data and image data is preserved and doesn't need to be fetched anew. Also this method is gazillion times faster than adding the new HTML via string.

```js
function startthefun() {
    var imgElem = document.createElement('img');
    imgElem.setAttribute('src','http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg?v=1bc6a0c03b68');
    document.getElementById('content').appendChild(imgElem);
    window.timer = window.setInterval(function() {document.body.appendChild(imgElem.cloneNode());},1000);
    }
```

```html
<input type="button" value="start" onclick="startthefun()"><input type="button" onclick="window.clearInterval(window.timer)" value="stahp"><div id="content"></div>
```

You can just simply feed the HTMLElement into the `$(selector).append(HTMLElement)` Jquery will append the html node to your selected item.

Comment: Hi  , mine is chat application and I have 100's of different images for different users ..how to use your function  ? Should i pass variable in function ? I also have msg and other stuffs to append.

Comment: Just make a new img element and adjust src attribute accordingly. Or do $(imgselector)[0].cloneNode() for each new image.

Comment: When i append it just appends as text [object HTMLImageElement]

Comment: And here you go, I might have gone a bit overboard, but this is the best way you could approach it imho ;-) http://www.liveweave.com/uM9Ayk

Comment: Thanks alot @michael +1.. I am using your code..But main problem was not setting cache header in php...After setting that even normal append is working properly :)

Comment: Good to hear. At least you now have a very fast chat application.